# Android Achartengine: Real Time bar chart

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, real-time, bar-chart, achartengine

I'm trying to get a bar chart that plots, in real time , the wifi received signal strength .
Well i'm using a brodcastreceiver ,to get the RSSI changes, and the achartengine to plot those information .But i'm just having the  bar chart for the first received data, and eiven if RSSI data is changing ,nothing happens on my chart.

**EDIT**

Well i guess i know why i have the first chart ,the methode getTruitonBarDataset is executing just one time ,can someone tell me how can i fix that.Thank you in advance.

**This the onReceive methode from the brodcastreceiver class :**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int length ;
            if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)){
                 List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
                 length=results.size();

                   Log.i("length1",length +"");
                    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getTruitonBarRenderer(results.size());
                    myChartSettings(renderer);

                       if (mChartView == null)
                       {mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(WifiChartsRealTime.this, getTruitonBarDataset( results), renderer, Type.STACKED); 
                       layout.addView(mChartView);} 
                       else {mChartView.repaint();}  


             }


        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you able to see log message **"length1"** each time when an intent is broadcasted?

Comment: yes ,i'm eaven seing results list(in a toast) ,changing every time ,but the chart still with the fist received data.

Comment: never worked with achartengine, but don't you think you need to **removeView** and re-add **mChartView**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780085/achartengine-remove-chart-before-and-redraw-new-chart

Comment: Thaaaaankss finely it's woooorking Thanks @waqaslam :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to waqaslam and  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780085/achartengine-remove-chart-before-and-redraw-new-chart) ,its working and this is my receive method :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            WifiManager wifiMan=(WifiManager)WifiChartsRealTime.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
              wifiMan.startScan();


            if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)){
                 results = wifi.getScanResults();
                 length=results.size();


                   Log.i("length1",length +"");
                    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getTruitonBarRenderer(results.size());
                    myChartSettings(renderer);




                       layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
                       if (mChartView != null) {
                           layout.removeView(mChartView);
                        }
                       mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(WifiChartsRealTime.this, getTruitonBarDataset( results), renderer, Type.STACKED); 
                       layout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


            }



        }`
```

Comment: Glad that it helped and +1 for the fact that you don't leave your question unanswered :)